# How to open a txt file of IR temperatures as an image in matlab or other analysis software

Tags: matlab, image-processing, infrared

I am using a therm-app camera to take infra-red photos of bats.  I would like to draw around parts of the bat and find the hottest, coldest and average temperature and do further analysis.

The software that comes with the camera doesn't let me draw polygons so I would like to load the image in another program such as MATLAB or maybe imageJ (also happy to use Python or other if that would work).

The camera creates 4 files total:

I have a .jpg file, however when I open this in MATLAB it just appears as an image and I think it is just opening as a normal image, not sure how to accurately get the temperatures from this. I used the following to open it:

```
im=imread('C:\18. Bats\20190321_064039.jpg');
imshow(im);
```

I also have three other files, two are metadata (e.g. show date-time emissivity settings etc.) and one is a text file.

The text file appears to show the temperature of every pixel in the image.

e.g. (for a photo that had a minimum temperature of 15deg and max of 20deg it would be a text file with a minimum value of 1500 and maximum value of 2000)

1516 1530 1530 1540 1600 1600 1600 1600 1536 1536 ........

This file looks very useful, just wondering if there is some way I can open this as an image, probably in a program like MATLAB, which I think has image analysis so that I could draw around certain parts of the image (e.g. the wing of the bat) and find the average, max, min etc.
Has anyone had experience with this type of thing, can I just assign colours to numbers somehow? Or maybe other people have done it already and there is a much easier way. I will keep searching on the internet also and try to find out.

Alternatively maybe I need to open the .jpg image, draw around different parts, write a program to find out which pixels I drew around, find these in the txt file and then do averaging etc?  Or somehow link the values in the text file to the .jpg file.

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, I can't find an image processing site on stack exchange.

All help is really appreciated, I will continue searching on the internet in the meantime.

Comment: what's the structure of the text file, is it a CSV type file, or tabs spaced array etc...  you can look into `csvread` or `dlmread` commands

Comment: Hi bla, thanks!  it's a .txt file the numbers in the file are separated by one space only, so I guess that's very similar to csv except using space as the separator.  Will look up those commands :)

Comment: Thanks, dlmread worked, once I've got everything exactly right I'll reply with more info.

Comment: Sounds cool - maybe share a set of the files via Dropbox or Google Drive along with anything you know about the dimensions of the file and I'll take a look.

Comment: Specifying the thermal camera make and model would help too.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  thanks very much, I think I'm actually getting it working, it was a whole lot easier than I thought it would be.  I can still send you the files if you're interested? I'm not sure how to load them onto stack overflow though?  Once I get it working completely I'll put a comment on how I did it.  I basically just opened it using dlmread then assigned the colours which only took 1 line also.  Now trying to work out how to get MATLAB to let me draw a polygon, assign a ROI and take averages etc.

Comment: p.s. camera is a "Therm-app TH".

Comment: No worries - if you have got it working, don't worry, carry on. Good luck!

Comment: @bla thanks!, I got it working now, have put the code I used as an answer below in case it is helpful to other people. However if you want to post dlmread as and answer I will mark that as correct as that was what solved it for me really.

Comment: no worries @shara , these are virtual unicorn points anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

the following worked in the end, it was much much easier than I thought it would be. Now a big fan of MATLAB, I thought it could take days to do this.

Just pasting here in case it is useful to someone else.  I'm sure there is a more elegant way to write the code, however this is the first time I've used MATLAB in 20 years :p   Use at your own risk, I haven't double checked I'm getting the correct results yet (though will do before I use it for anything important).

- edit, since writing this I've found that the output .txt file of temperatures is actually sensor temperatures which need to be corrected for emissivity and background temperature to obtain the target temperatures.  (One way to do this is to use the software which comes free with the camera to create new output .csv files of temperatures and use those instead).

Thanks to bla who put me on the right track with dlmread.

```
M=dlmread('C:\18. Bats\20190321_064039\20190321_064039_temps.txt')  % read in the text file as a matrix (call it M)
                          % note that file seems to be a list of temperature values for each pixel 
                          % e.g. 1934 1935 1935 1960 2000 2199... 
M = rot90( M , 1 )  % rotate M anti-clockwise by 1*90  (All the pictures were saved sideways for some reason so rotate for easier viewing)
a = min(M(:));      % find the minimum temperature in the image
b = max(M(:));      % find the maximum temperature in the image
imresize(M,1.64);   % resize the image to fit the computer screen prior to showing it on the screen

imshow(M,[a b]);    % show image on the screen and fit the colours so that white is the value with the highest temperature in the image (b) and black is the lowest (a).

h = drawpolygon('FaceAlpha',0);     % Let the user draw a polygon around the region of interest (ROI) 
                                %(this stops code until polygon is drawn)

maskOfROI = h.createMask();         % For each pixel in the image assign a binary number, pixels inside the polygon (ROI) area are given 1 outside are 0
selectedValues = M(maskOfROI);      % Now get the image values for all pixels where the mask value is '1' (i.e. all pixels within the polygon) and call this selectedValues.


averageTemperature = mean(selectedValues);     % Get the mean of selectedValues (i.e. mean of the temperatures inside the polygon area)
maxTemperature = max(selectedValues);          % Get the max of selectedValues
minTemperature = min(selectedValues);          % Get the min of selectedValues
```